# Role of indices parameters in glDrawElements with GL_POINTS

Tags: opengl, graphics

What is the role of the indices parameter in the glDrawElements function when the mode is set to GL_POINTS? 
I have the following piece of code:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_SHORT, 0, spaceCoordinates);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glTexCoordPointer(3, GL_SHORT, 0, spaceCoordinates);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl_rgb_tex);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, 640, 480, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, globalRGB);
glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 640*480, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);
```

where indices[i] = i; 
If I dont want a vertex to be drawn, how should I tamper with indices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want some vertexes to be drawn, then you need to change the `count` and remove those vertexes indexes from the `indices` array.